# Autenticação de Web Service Restful com PHP

Tags: php, web-service, autenticação, restful

Olá estou desenvolvendo uma api Restful, porém gostaria de saber se é seguro autenticar o usuários passando o token na url? E se existe algum outro método mais seguro.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente os tokens de acesso costumam, dependendo da configuração do endpoint, ter um tempo de vida de uma hora.

Pela URL não costuma ser o método mais seguro, já que ele fica exposto mesmo em conexões seguras. O ideal é passar o token por meio do cabeçalho de `Authorization`, da seguinte forma:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Esse método faz parte do framework de autorização OAuth 2.0. Leia mais no [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

Comment: E para armazenar esse token no client local storange é a melhor opção?

Comment: Esse token vai ser usado nos cabeçalhos até expirar, e então você o renova usando as credenciais do usuário ou um refresh token. O ideal é que você o armazene de alguma forma até isso acontecer.

Answer (score 1):

> Gostaria de saber se é seguro autenticar o usuários passando o token na url? E se existe algum outro método mais seguro.

Não é seguro passar a autenticação toda pela url. Em regra, não passe dados críticos através da URL porque essas informações são facilmente interceptadas por pessoas maliciosas, mesmo que o seu Token tenha validade isso pode comprometer a segurança.

*Eu nunca posso passar token pela url?* Pode passar um complemento do token ou algo somente verificador, mas informações realmente importantes devem estar dentro de cabeçalhos ou através de métodos como o POST e não por GET.

**Utilize OAuth 2.0**

Recomendo que utilize o [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/), ele é utilizado por empresas como o Facebook, o Google, o PayPal, o Twitter etc. Serve tanto como servidor de autorização quanto de autenticação. No [site oficial](http://oauth.net/2/) encontramos exemplos de implementação do sistema em diversas linguagens.

**Man-in-the-middle**

Não esqueça de usar a camada de segurança, SSL, na sua aplicação ou pode comprometer a segurança dela com o famoso [*man-in-the-middle*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle). Aqui tem um [artigo bem interessante sobre esse ataque](http://blog.corujadeti.com.br/entendendo-ataques-man-in-the-middle/) dividido em quatro partes, recomendo a leitura.